# how do i split large binary file on certain byte header in vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net

I have a very large binary file 250 gigs working to split this file into smaller files starting from a certain bytes header until a new header or end-of-file is reached i want this part to be stored as a separate new file for each case like this.

1. looking for certain byte pattern.(header)
2. have to save all the data till first occurrence (excluding the header).
3. starting from the first occurrence of header all data will be save until a second header is found in a separate file.
4. all the data from first occurrence till end of file will be stored as separate file.

   ```
   Sub hexDumpFile(fil As String)
       Using reader As New BinaryReader(File.Open(fil, FileMode.Open))
           ' Loop through length of file.
           Dim pos As Integer = 0
           Dim length As Long = reader.BaseStream.Length
           'looking up for 00 00 01 BA 44 00 04 00 04
           Dim header(9) As Byte
           Dim buff(18) As Byte   
           header = {&H0, &H0, &H1, &HBA, &H44, &H0, &H4, &H0, &H4}
           buff.Initialize()
           Dim i As Integer
           While pos < length - buff.Length
               '--- Read the integer.
               buff.Initialize()
               buff = reader.ReadBytes(buff.length)
               Console.Write(Hex(pos) & ":")
               ' Write to screen.
               Try
                   For i = 0 To buff.Length
                       Console.Write(Hex(buff(i))) hex value
                       Console.Write(" ") ' space
                   Next
                   Console.WriteLine("") ' line break

               Catch EX As Exception
                   Console.WriteLine(EX.Source.ToString)
                   Console.WriteLine(EX.Message)
               End Try
               ' Add length of integer in bytes to position.
               pos += 1
           End While
       End Using
   End Sub
   ```

### Problems:

1. can not avoid exceptions --> Index was outside the bounds of the array.
2. can not find first match
3. can not save separate files

Comment: Problem 4. Not showing us the full exception you receive, 5. Not telling us why you can't save separate files.

Comment: ans:to problem 4: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Where does `diff` come from, as in `reader.ReadBytes(diff.length)`? Did you mean `buff.length`?

Comment: ans:to problem 5: since i can not find the byte header location so i can not pass to binarystream.writer.

Comment: SORRY: for mis-typing it was suposed to be `buff`

Comment: 1. On what line is your exception occurring? 2. None of your code seems to be searching for any matches. I'd suggest looping through the bytes in buff one at a time to search for the first instance of &H0. If you find one, check if the next byte is &H0, then &H1, and so on. 3. You have nothing to save until you sort problem #2.

Comment: Console.Write("0" & Hex(buff(i)))

Comment: Change `For i = 0 To buff.Length` to `For i = 0 To buff.Length - 1`.

Comment: thanks for you hint -- they say "two pair of eyes are always better than one".  thanks Justin Ryan